# Root Samsung Galaxy Tab A 8.0 (SM-T290)

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-tab-a

Good morning. I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab A 8.0 a.k.a SM-T290 and I would be pleased if someone tell me how to get root access to it. Already have tried the method described in:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-a/how-to/how-to-root-tablet-a8-2019-t290-t4119487 https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-a/how-to/root-sm-t290-tab-8-0-2019-t3965624

And neither with the first method or the second was able to root my device. Thanks in advance.